# Why docker-storage-setup doesn't create thin pool for overlayfs driver?

Tags: docker, lvm

Seen from the docker-storage-setup code(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/projectatomic/docker-storage-setup/master/docker-storage-setup.sh), docker-storage-setup will create thin pool(docker-pool) and enable_auto_pool_extension with devicemapper driver, but not do that with overlayfs driver. Is it the matter of Docker or the file system(overlay) itself which confilts with lvm?

Comment: Could you please explain your question a bit more? I'm confused as to what you're asking.

Comment: @karobar oh, sorry for that. From the script above, if I set docker_storage_driver=device mapper , then it will create a thin pool named docker-pool as the backend storage for docker, but if I set docker_storage_driver=overlay, the script would not create a thin pool, and it will use the "/" partition as the backend storage for docker. What confused me is why there is difference with this two kinds of driver. Is it because overlay doesn't support thin pool?